# Beginner and Blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Simple question.

I have a tableViewController that will display a list of search results.

I want to create a block based callback (I think that's what you would call it)

I would present the viewController

```
[searchResultController showSearchResults //BlockCode here {

//did select this item...

}];
```

but use a block so that I can detect the selection made from the tableview instead of using a delegate method.

Problem is I have no idea how to implement this. Is there a good tutorial or a simple example on how to do this?

Comment: why do you want to do this? it's probably going to be harder to do this than to just implement the delegate and `didSelectRowAtIndex`

Comment: you can take a look at existing code, you can find quite a few categories for UIAlertViews that add block callbacks.

Comment: I'm doing this because I want to create a class to handle my data seperate from my view controllers. So I created method that will return 1 result.. I first search for some items. If 1 items is found it returns the one result. If 2 or more results come back I need to present the searchResultsViewController and let the user decide. I need to get the answer within the same method I'm showing the results. Unless I want to use delegates but I want to use blocks because it's something new that I need to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search results controller needs to have a block property. This block should be defined with no return type, and should take a parameter of whatever object you are going to use to represent the selected item.

Before presenting your search results controller, set the block property to whatever you wish to do for your callback.

Within the search results controller, when a row is selected, execute the block, passing in the selected object. Either this method, or the block itself, should also dismiss your controller.